# datefinder.find_dates() is not able to extract date from a string when the date is followed by the terms "last", "until"

Tags: python, datefinder

I was trying to extract date from strings using datefinder. I observed that datefinder.find_dates() is not able to extract date from a string when the date is followed by "last" ,"until"

```
  text= "Created 2009.10.20last-modified"
  list(datefinder.find_dates(text))
  
  O/P : []

  text= "Created 2009.10.20until-modified"
  list(datefinder.find_dates(text))   
  
  O/P : []         

  text= "Created 2009.10.20registration"
  list(datefinder.find_dates(text))    
  
  O/P : [datetime.datetime(2009, 10, 20, 0, 0)]
```

Are they reserved words in datefinder? Can someone please advise on how to handle such strings?

Comment: You mean [this](https://github.com/akoumjian/datefinder/blob/master/datefinder/constants.py)?

Comment: I have a solution if use parser(from dateutil import parser) . This will give you date as output.

Answer (score 0):

Parser will extract the date with '-'. You can use this.

```
from dateutil import parser

# initializing string
#test_str = "Created 2009.10.20last-modified"
test_str= "Created 2009.10.25until-modified"

# printing original string
print("The original string is : " + str(test_str))

# extracting date using inbuilt func.
res = parser.parse(test_str, fuzzy=True)

# printing result
print("Computed date : " + str(res)[:10])
```

Output:

```
The original string is : Created 2009.10.25until-modified
Computed date : 2009-10-25
```

Comment: i want a solution wrt datefinder becoz i have strings with more than one date. And if there are multiple dates in a string, parser function raises an Error.